# Generate all possible comparisons 3 v 3 in a group of 6

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have 6 samples and I would like to generate all possible 3v3 comparisons using python.
So far I've managed to use the combinations function to generate all possible groups of 3. But I fail to generate the match comparisons (if I have CM26 in the first group I don't want to compare it against a group of 3 with it).

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
columns = {'CM19':1,'CM20':2,'CM21':3,'CM23':5,'CM25':7,'CM26':8}
for i in combinations(columns,3):
    print i
```

> ('CM26', 'CM19', 'CM25') ('CM26', 'CM19', 'CM23') ('CM26', 'CM19',
>   'CM20') ('CM26', 'CM19', 'CM21') ('CM26', 'CM25', 'CM23') ('CM26',
>   'CM25', 'CM20') ('CM26', 'CM25', 'CM21') ('CM26', 'CM23', 'CM20')
>   ('CM26', 'CM23', 'CM21') ('CM26', 'CM20', 'CM21') ('CM19', 'CM25',
>   'CM23') ('CM19', 'CM25', 'CM20') ('CM19', 'CM25', 'CM21') ('CM19',
>   'CM23', 'CM20') ('CM19', 'CM23', 'CM21') ('CM19', 'CM20', 'CM21')
>   ('CM25', 'CM23', 'CM20') ('CM25', 'CM23', 'CM21') ('CM25', 'CM20',
>   'CM21') ('CM23', 'CM20', 'CM21')

I would like to compare each group to the others but eliminating repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always pick a triple with the first element present, and use the complement of the set for the other triple.

Here's code.

```
import itertools

def three_vs_three(xs):
    xset = set(xs)
    for i1, i2 in itertools.combinations(xs[1:], 2):
        triple = set([xs[0], i1, i2])
        yield sorted(triple), sorted(xset - triple)

things = ['CM%d' % x for x in 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26]
print list(three_vs_three(things))
```

Comment: Oh, the `-` operator is the same as saying `set.difference(set1, set2)`? I've wasted so much time typing the set operations... :/

Answer (score 1):

The two tricks to solving this are the following:

1. You can use `itertools.permutations` with the second parameter of 3 to generate sets of 3 elements
2. You can use `set.difference` to figure out the compliment for any generated tuple in Step 1

---

```
group = set(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
import itertools

comparisons = [(tuple(i),tuple(set.difference(group,i))) for i in itertools.permutations(group,3)]
```

Result

```
[(('A', 'C', 'B'), ('E', 'D', 'F')),
 (('A', 'C', 'E'), ('B', 'D', 'F')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'E', 'F')),
 (('A', 'C', 'F'), ('B', 'E', 'D')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('E', 'D', 'F')),
 (('A', 'B', 'E'), ('C', 'D', 'F')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('C', 'E', 'F')),
 (('A', 'B', 'F'), ('C', 'E', 'D')),
 (('A', 'E', 'C'), ('B', 'D', 'F')),
 (('A', 'E', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'F')),
 (('A', 'E', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'F')),
 (('A', 'E', 'F'), ('C', 'B', 'D')),
 (('A', 'D', 'C'), ('B', 'E', 'F')),
 (('A', 'D', 'B'), ('C', 'E', 'F')),
 (('A', 'D', 'E'), ('C', 'B', 'F')),
 (('A', 'D', 'F'), ('C', 'B', 'E')),
 (('A', 'F', 'C'), ('B', 'E', 'D')),
 (('A', 'F', 'B'), ('C', 'E', 'D')),
 (('A', 'F', 'E'), ('C', 'B', 'D')),
 (('A', 'F', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'E')),
 (('C', 'A', 'B'), ('E', 'D', 'F')),
 (('C', 'A', 'E'), ('B', 'D', 'F')),
 (('C', 'A', 'D'), ('B', 'E', 'F')),
 (('C', 'A', 'F'), ('B', 'E', 'D')),
 (('C', 'B', 'A'), ('E', 'D', 'F')),
 (('C', 'B', 'E'), ('A', 'D', 'F')),
 (('C', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'E', 'F')),
 (('C', 'B', 'F'), ('A', 'E', 'D')),
 (('C', 'E', 'A'), ('B', 'D', 'F')),
 (('C', 'E', 'B'), ('A', 'D', 'F')),
 (('C', 'E', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'F')),
 (('C', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'D')),
 (('C', 'D', 'A'), ('B', 'E', 'F')),
 (('C', 'D', 'B'), ('A', 'E', 'F')),
 (('C', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'F')),
 (('C', 'D', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'E')),
 (('C', 'F', 'A'), ('B', 'E', 'D')),
 (('C', 'F', 'B'), ('A', 'E', 'D')),
 (('C', 'F', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'D')),
 (('C', 'F', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'E')),
 (('B', 'A', 'C'), ('E', 'D', 'F')),
 (('B', 'A', 'E'), ('C', 'D', 'F')),
 (('B', 'A', 'D'), ('C', 'E', 'F')),
 (('B', 'A', 'F'), ('C', 'E', 'D')),
 (('B', 'C', 'A'), ('E', 'D', 'F')),
 (('B', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'D', 'F')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'E', 'F')),
 (('B', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'E', 'D')),
 (('B', 'E', 'A'), ('C', 'D', 'F')),
 (('B', 'E', 'C'), ('A', 'D', 'F')),
 (('B', 'E', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'F')),
 (('B', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'D')),
 (('B', 'D', 'A'), ('C', 'E', 'F')),
 (('B', 'D', 'C'), ('A', 'E', 'F')),
 (('B', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'F')),
 (('B', 'D', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'E')),
 (('B', 'F', 'A'), ('C', 'E', 'D')),
 (('B', 'F', 'C'), ('A', 'E', 'D')),
 (('B', 'F', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'D')),
 (('B', 'F', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'E')),
 (('E', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'D', 'F')),
 (('E', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'F')),
 (('E', 'A', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'F')),
 (('E', 'A', 'F'), ('C', 'B', 'D')),
 (('E', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'D', 'F')),
 (('E', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'D', 'F')),
 (('E', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'F')),
 (('E', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'D')),
 (('E', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'D', 'F')),
 (('E', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'D', 'F')),
 (('E', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'F')),
 (('E', 'B', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'D')),
 (('E', 'D', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'F')),
 (('E', 'D', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'F')),
 (('E', 'D', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'F')),
 (('E', 'D', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'B')),
 (('E', 'F', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'D')),
 (('E', 'F', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D')),
 (('E', 'F', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'D')),
 (('E', 'F', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'B')),
 (('D', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'E', 'F')),
 (('D', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'E', 'F')),
 (('D', 'A', 'E'), ('C', 'B', 'F')),
 (('D', 'A', 'F'), ('C', 'B', 'E')),
 (('D', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'E', 'F')),
 (('D', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'E', 'F')),
 (('D', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'F')),
 (('D', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'E')),
 (('D', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'E', 'F')),
 (('D', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'E', 'F')),
 (('D', 'B', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'F')),
 (('D', 'B', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'E')),
 (('D', 'E', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'F')),
 (('D', 'E', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'F')),
 (('D', 'E', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'F')),
 (('D', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'B')),
 (('D', 'F', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'E')),
 (('D', 'F', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'E')),
 (('D', 'F', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'E')),
 (('D', 'F', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'B')),
 (('F', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'E', 'D')),
 (('F', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'E', 'D')),
 (('F', 'A', 'E'), ('C', 'B', 'D')),
 (('F', 'A', 'D'), ('C', 'B', 'E')),
 (('F', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'E', 'D')),
 (('F', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'E', 'D')),
 (('F', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'D')),
 (('F', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'E')),
 (('F', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'E', 'D')),
 (('F', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'E', 'D')),
 (('F', 'B', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'D')),
 (('F', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'E')),
 (('F', 'E', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'D')),
 (('F', 'E', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D')),
 (('F', 'E', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'D')),
 (('F', 'E', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'B')),
 (('F', 'D', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'E')),
 (('F', 'D', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'E')),
 (('F', 'D', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'E')),
 (('F', 'D', 'E'), ('A', 'C', 'B'))]
```

Comment: A last twist. What about generating only the ones without repetition (i.e. ('C','B','D'),('A','E','F') is the same that ('C','B','D'),('A','F','E').